# Associations and models for structure of comments and subcomments

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am in doubt on how to do the modeling of my database to the following structure:

I have a post that has comments and this comments may or may not have many subcomments and these subcomments can have many comments / subcomments and so on.

One example of my structure:

[image]

I know I have to have a comment table, but I'm not sure whether I'll have to create a has_many relation throught with a table subcomments, or do this through auto-realignment. Can anyone give you an idea?

I added self join to comments:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Comment"
  has_many :child_comments, :class_name => "Comment", :foreign_key => "parent_id"
end
```

My other models are:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :body, presence: true
end


class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments
end
```

When i tried create a new comment with:

> Comment.create(body: 'comment', user_id: 1, post_id: 1, parent_id: 1)

I got:

> (0.6ms)  BEGIN   User Load (66.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"
>   WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]   Post
>   Load (35.8ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1
>   LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]   Comment Load (13.4ms)  SELECT 
>   "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2 
>   [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]    (0.5ms)  ROLLBACK
>   => #

Answer (score 0):

I would use a self-referential model, something like:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Comment"
  has_many :child_comments, :class_name => "Comment", :foreign_key => "parent_id"
end
```

This will create a tree structure model where every comment will belong to a parent.

Comment: Hm ... but the comment may not have parent if it is the main comment like 1.1 in the image.

Comment: When i try create a comment with: Comment.create(body: 'comment', user_id: 1, post_id: 1, parent_id: 1) the database don't accept and get rollback

Comment: I edited my question with logs and others informations.